# How to know if a resource is protected in a jsr-196 auth module?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I wrote a custom JSR-196 module, which combines multiple mechanisms to protect resources.

It works quite well if authentication is provided.

Now, if a *protected* resource is accessed and authentication isn't provided, I'd like to redirect my user to some login page.

How can I know that a resource is protected? I don't want to redirect for unprotected images or for the login page itself. I used web.xml to allow unrestricted access to that. For those pages, sending AuthStatus.SUCCESS seems to be the only way to display them. I'd rather think I need to send AuthStatus.SEND_CONTINUE. And I'd need a way to tell if I need to restrict access on those.

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I somehow removed the requestPolicy.isMandatory() check...

That's where the magic happens, it tells you if a resource is protected.

I thought requestPolicy was tied to the ServerAuthModule. Now, this is true, but a different ServerAuthModule is created for protected and unprotected resource.